# Low side high side NTC measurement

Tags: voltage-divider, thermistor

[image]I am using 100k NTC from Murata (SMD, 0603 package) for temperature Measurement. I will drive NTC (*MCU_Output*) only when i need to measure the temperature. Which of the following options is better?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu3qE8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sink and source current is about 10 mA. I am looking at best interface in terms of quiescent current and impedance (I need more help here).

I have added the ADC section impedance details.

Comment: I doubt if either will work very well - what processor are you using and what is the input impedance of the inbuilt ADC? Also, are you planning on measuring ratiometrically?

Comment: @AndyAka MCU: R5F10WLDAFA. May use Steinhart Equation in MCU. Not sure about Software,honestly.

Comment: I don't know that chip - you need to look at its data sheet for the ADC specification.

Comment: @AndyAka can you please help me in finding the information about impedance? Datasheet link: http://am.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/rl78/rl78l1x/rl78l13/device/R5F10WLDAFA__Documentation.jsp    Page number 443 has ADC details.

Comment: @AndyAka I have added the ADC impedance details from the MCU datasheet. I am new to this but will learn obediently. can you please guide me here

Comment: Can you provide a direct link to the data sheet and not to the page you linked previously.

Comment: @AndyAka : here it is: http://am.renesas.com/req/product_document_lineup_child.do?REGION_KEY=3&LAYER_KEY=85282&PDF_URL=http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/rl78/r01uh0382ej0200_rl78l13.pdf&TKUPDATE=true&APNOTE=true&AUTHORFLG=

Comment: @Andyaka I am planning to use 10k, 0.1% with 10k NTC. External cap of 10nF. Please consider these in your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am planning to use 10k, 0.1% with 10k NTC. External cap of 10nF.
>   Please consider these in your views

[image]

1Kohm is the limiting value and with 10k values, the effective resistance is 5kohms so, use a much bigger capacitor as recommended.

Regarding the CPU switching the 10k, with two 10k resistors in series and (say) a 5V supply, the current is 0.25mA and rising as the NTC gets warmer. Is this too much overhead current if left in place all the time? If so then my recommendation is to use a MOSFET (activated by one of the gpios) to apply power to the resistors when needed. In this way you can probably use 1k resistors and problem solved.

---

> can you please help me in understanding about source impedance

A battery has a very low source impedance. If it didn't it wouldn't be able to supply amps of current. If you added resistance in series with the battery its source impedance would appear to be the value of the resistor + the internal source resistance of the battery. Vdd is your source and although it can't supply amps it's probably regulated so that for 0 mA to maybe 0.5 amps it appears to have a very low source impedance (maybe 0.01 ohms).

So across your resistor network is, what amounts to a zero source impedance supply. If your thermistor and resistor were both 1kohm, the midpoint voltage would have a source resistance that is half of 1kohm. Does this make sense?

Comment: The thermistor could be > 10x the 25°C value on a moderately cold day (-20°C), depending on \$\beta\$. At least you can count on the fixed resistor.

Comment: @Andyaka can you please help me in understanding about source impedance

Comment: @Umar added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Why the source impedance still is half a kilo Ohm? I thought it will be 1 kOhm because that is in series with the supply just before the tapping point. I am wrong I know. I want to know how it is .5 kOhm

Comment: You have two sources - one is 0V via 1k and the other is the supply (via 1k). This effectively means, as far as impedance goes, that the source impedance is the parallel sum of the two.

Comment: @Andyaka then, even with 1k resistors, i will be getting only half of the input voltage at ADC. am i Right? Should source impedance (resistance) shouldn't be several times less than input impedance of ADC?

Comment: The source impedance is stated as "no greater than 1k ohm" in the spec above.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Datasheet hints that ADC input might be about 10k or more, probably. I could get some knowledge based on your explanations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your voltage divider will run at a few µA current - at such a current, there will be no difference in sinking or sourcing ability.  Given that all current MCUs are based on CMOS (not not TTL), the MCU should also be able to pull its pin to either rail.  Personally, I'd go for the current sink solution (option 2).

Comment: And the ADC input impedance issue (much more important that a digital output issue)?

Comment: The impedance could be a problem, but that's not what I understand the question to be about.

Comment: @corecode I am interested in finding out when the MCU is driving low in case of option 1, there will be small leakage current. How much will that be?

Comment: @corecode The ADC is intimately linked to this question even if the questioner doesn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

The impedance presented to the ADC input is the same in both circuits. You just need to let the input capacitance charge before you take the measurement. Make sure the voltage is present for a short time (say 10 x RC) so the voltage is settled. R is your source impedance from the measurement circuit which will be the parallel combination of the two resistors (say 5k) and C is the first capacitor 8pf. This comes out at 0.4uSec. Settling time. RC for the second step will be similar (R is about 20k, C is 7.5p), so this requires similar settling. I suggest 1-2 uSec delay after powering before starting the measurement.

Take care with option 2. Some ADC inputs need to stay below the reference voltage, Your second option will take the ADC input to the vcc rail when turned off.

Comment: Is 5k, the equivalent thevenin's resistor?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the correct place to put the switch is on the side of the 100K resistor because that will result in minimum measurement error at high thermistor temperature. That would be your option 2, but the inverse (option 4?) might or might not be somewhat better depending on where other currents are flowing and whether the output pin sinks better than it sources. It's also bad juju to connect a sensor to an i/o pin directly if it goes any distance from the micro.

You could also use the output to switch a small MOSFET that would have << 1 ohm of resistance, then it wouldn't matter.

The other issue is that the ADC prefers to see a source impedance of 1K or less, and your source impedance will approach 100K at low temperatures. So you'd best use a voltage follower buffer ahead of the ADC- a rail-to-rail input/output (RRIO) op-amp would work nicely.

Comment: How did you find out that ADC required an impedance of 1k or less? Pls help me in learning about that. is it specific to this ADC or it is inherent? Also, I cannot afford an Opamp that is rail to rail. (Power + Cost). Thank you for your time!

Comment: Data sheet. You can go a bit higher than 1K with extended acquisition time. Most micros will not like 100K source impedance.

Comment: Now I am going with 10k, 0.1% resistor with 10K NTC. Slow acquisition time (10ms or higher), 10nF external capacitor.